# Native Android mobile app test automaton navigation with multiple class elements

Tags: android, python, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

[image]

How do you enter text (password), when there is no `text`, `resource-id`, `content-desc` and there is more than one class? i.e. the class name for the `username` is also `android.widget.EditText`. I've tried xpath or UISelector as follows, yet it doesn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='']").send_keys("xxxx")

driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator("new UiSelector().text('')")
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try looking by a class name? You can try the following:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.EditText')
```

If you have more than one element with similar class, find all of them:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('android.widget.EditText')
```

And then you have 2 options.:

1. You can iterate over the located elements and check if you can get some meaningful text from each one of them by calling `element.text`. This is as an attempt to find which element might return something related to password.
2. If there is no way to reliably identify which one of the elements is the one you need you will have to just select a predefined element from the list. For example: `passField = elements[0]`.